# ANSI prompts messed in Ubuntu 10.04 terminal window (Unicode 0002), but ok in Putty

Tags: ubuntu, bash, prompt, ansi

My bash prompt is:

```
PS1='\e[1;31m\]\[\u\e[0m\]@\h [\e[1;33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]]\$ '
```

(reddish username, yellowish current directory).

If I connect with Putty from a Windows machine, everything is fine.
If I open a terminal window from within the Ubuntu Desktop (a fresh install of 10.04 TLS), the first character of the username and the first character of the path are replaced with Unicode +0002 (a square box showing is drawn in ASCII text below).

```
 __
|00|
|02|
 __
```

The character encoding in the Ubuntu terminal is UTF-8. Putty's translation setting which does the same thing is UTF-8 as well.

Any hints of what is wrong would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a couple of brackets and backslashes are out of place. Give this a try:

```
PS1='\[\e[1;31m\][\u\[\e[0m\]@\h \[\e[1;33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]]\$ '
```